# iOS >> UIBarButton >> Set Identifier from Code

Tags: ios, properties, uibarbuttonitem, identifier

I have a UIBarButton in a Navigation Bar (the VC is embedded within a Navigation Controller).
In IB I set the button with an Identifier:

[image: Bar Button in Navigation Bar]
[image: Attributes Inspector]

How do I set this Attribute from code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set it like

```
UIBarButtonItem *trashButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:nil];
```

Check out the Apple Documentation for this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem%3atarget%3aaction%3a)

Unfortunately, Apple only allow you to set this when you initialize the `UIBarButtonItem` there isn't a property to set this.

Comment: So it means I have to create a new button every time? I read the documentation and it seemed weird there's no Property or a setIdentifier:ForState method...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there isn't a property you can just set you have to do it when you `alloc init`. Annoying but that's just the way Apple like - annoying.